# Why do DNS queries fail if the first nameserver is not recursive?

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

I have a Linux box (Ubuntu server 11.10) inside a Windows Active Directory domain, and is joined the domain using [likewise-open](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen). The `resolv.conf` file looks like this:

```
domain mydomain.com
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

where `192.168.1.1` is the Windows DNS server for the Windows domain. `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` are Google's public DNS servers that we preferred over our ISP servers.

That setup was working properly, until we decided to disable recursion in the Windows DNS server due to some changes of our network design. I thought that will go well as we have configured it to use Google's servers next, but it seems not:

```
mydomain\myuser@linux-server:~$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55321
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 13, ADDITIONAL: 4
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       3600    IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       3600    IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       3600    IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       3600    IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       3600    IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       3600    IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       3600    IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       3600    IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       3600    IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       3600    IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       3600    IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       3600    IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       3600    IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
c.root-servers.net.     3600    IN      A       192.33.4.12
d.root-servers.net.     3600    IN      A       128.8.10.90
e.root-servers.net.     3600    IN      A       192.203.230.10
f.root-servers.net.     3600    IN      A       192.5.5.241

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan  8 14:02:22 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 507
```

Also:

```
mydomain\myuser@linux-server:~$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

And also I have failed squid proxy connections (which I solved using the [dns_nameservers](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/dns_nameservers/) option inside squid configuration and neglected the internal DNS server).

Why DNS requests fails when recursion is declined by the first nameserver? Shouldn't the machine tries the next server? And what can I do if that was the expected (designed) behavior?

**EDIT:** NSLOOKUP gave other (success) results:

```
mydomain\myuser@linux-server:~$ nslookup google.com
;; Got recursion not available from 192.168.1.1, trying next server
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.67.102
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.67.138
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.67.100
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.67.113
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.67.139
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.67.101
```

So is this application-dependent? Can I get that (trying next server if the first refuses recursion) to work transparently for all applications requesting name resolution, or name resolution is the responsibility of the program itself? (or am I missing something?!)...

**EDIT:** Also worth noting, `mydomain.com` is a registered and public address on the internet and is not owned by us. It's like we've set up an internal domain named `apple.com`, and I assure you I don't work for Apple, at least not yet ;-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer will be "it depends".

As far as `dig` is concerned, it is basically a tool used to debug DNS information. Thus, it shows you the information it gets back from the nameserver you asked; it doesn't go on and make further questions.

For other programs, it will depend on the program. Most will probably use the operating system's functions for name resolution (see `man getnameinfo`). Others may not. This means that if you list a non-recursive nameserver, you will have some errors that will be very hard to locate.

In other words, keeping a non-recursive nameserver in your list of resolvers is a bad idea.

If you don't want the windows server to be recursive, then I'd recommend setting up a separate server to act as a resolver and let that one ask the Windows server for the internal domains.

Comment: Actually `mydomain.com` is a valid and registered domain on the internet, I think that may cause a problem to the other recursive domain, maybe?

Comment: Since 192.168.1.1 is not a publicly routable address, I was assuming that this was not your company's public nameserver. But if you already have a separate server to respond to queries for addresses within your domain, why keep this one in the resolver list at all? It would appear to serve no puprpose...

Comment: (Also, mydomain.com is a valid and registered domain, but is it really *yours*?)

Comment: No no, the local domain name is identical to other one that is used on the internet but not ours. Say, for example, that our local domain is `apple.com`!
P.S. I know that was a bad idea but it's the case already and is not subject to change now...

Comment: No, @Jenny it's not ours!!

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts - wish this was in all help centres...

Comment: didn't leak any of that :) although anyone want to guess can easily find the real details, but I try my best...